# Check array size and match value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a json response whose format is this -:

```
{"message":"Failed","NOTIFY":[{"code":"400","DATA":["abc"],"message":"already in use."}]}
```

If `NOTIFY[x].DATA` has a single value and the value is `abc` then I need to print the value of `NOTIFY[x].message` . Else print all values of DATA

I tried something like this below but I am getting `Undefined` value in my errMsg

```
for(let x in data.NOTIFY) {
  if(data.NOTIFY[x].hasOwnProperty('abc')) {
    if(data.NOTIFY[x].DATA =='LOYALTY'){
      errMsg = `ERROR: ${data.NOTIFY.message}`;
    } else {
      errMsg =  `ERROR: Invalid DATA: ${data.NOTIFY[x].DATA.join(", ")}`;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First, use the operator `of` instead.

Comment: Your object `NOTIFY` only have the properties of `code` and `DATA`, `'abc'` is a value of `DATA`. ie `data.NOTIFY.DATA[0] === 'abc'`.

Comment: How does `LOYALTY` fit into what you want to do?

Comment: You're overwriting `errMsg` every time through the loop. What if there are multiple errors?

Comment: @stwilz you got me , now it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that the `if(data.NOTIFY[x].hasOwnProperty('abc'))` doesnt match the data structure.

this seems to work:

```
const errors = data.NOTIFY.map(({ DATA, message }) => { 
  if (DATA.length === 1 && DATA[0] === 'abc') {
    return message;
  }
  return DATA.join(', ');
});

console.log(errors);
```

Comment: I think he was confusing `hasOwnProperty()` with `includes()`, although he forgot to specify `.DATA`.

Comment: But it is failing when json don't have DATA or message field. because of that i have added a check hasOwnProperty('fields') like that in my orginal code

Comment: @Developer when possible i would suggest using ES6 syntax: `'property' in object`.

If the data structure isnt trustable i would add something like `Array.isArray(DATA)` and avoid exceptions latter on your code.

Answer (score 0):

Added some more data
for better understanding on your concern...

```
let d = {
    "message": "Failed",
    "NOTIFY": [{
            "code": "400",
            "DATA": ["abc"],
            "message": "already in use only 1 data."
        },
        {
            "code": "400",
            "DATA": ["ac"],
            "message": "already in use 1 data."
        }, {
            "code": "400",
            "DATA": ["pqs", "xyz", "sssd", "wer", "pop"],
            "message": "already in use with 5 data."
        }, {
            "code": "400",
            "DATA": ["abc", 'XYZ'],
            "message": "already in use with 2 data."
        }
    ]
}
```

// use this piece of code inside your function

```
d.NOTIFY.map(item => {
    item.DATA.length === 1 && item.DATA[0] === 'abc' ?
        console.log(item.message, 'abc matched with only one data') :
        item.DATA.forEach(data =>
            console.log(data, 'abc unmatched or more data length'))
})
```